# Neo4jClient Data Import

Tags: neo4j, neo4jclient

I use Neo4jClient (.NET). I have to import master data like countries.

I've seen that Neo4j has a Java API for that ([the batch insertion API](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/batchinsert.html)). Is it possible to import data via the web interface or another tool?

If not, do I have to import the data via Neo4JClient wrapper with the `Create()` function?!

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It will be much faster if you grit your teeth and do this using the batch insertion API- either by writing an import script in Java or another JVM language or by using Michael Hunger's batch inserter, which inserts data from CSV. Check out Max de Marzi's [post on the topic](http://maxdemarzi.com/2012/02/28/batch-importer-part-1/) for a good approach.

Even though REST bindings are trying to offer decent performance, they'll never be as fast as native database access- and even if they were, the batch insertion API strips down some of the database features (multi-thread access, etc) to great improve initial import time.

Answer (score 0):

Also,
could you try using Cypher CREATE since that is not as fast as Batch, but faster than REST, and should let you create stuff fast.

http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/snapshot/cypher-cookbook-pretty-graphs.html gives some good hints ...

Answer (score 0):

Check out the Cypher neo4j import csv option. Maybe that helps. Otherwise just use a big Cypher query

http://neo4j.com/docs/milestone/query-load-csv.html