# Neo4JClient performance crawling a database

Tags: c#-4.0, neo4jclient

I am testing Neo4J as the searched database to my application's database (SQL Server or Oracle).  My intention is to crawl the RDBMS database and copy the searchable content to Neo4J.  Later when the user requests a search, I can use the graph searching capabilities of Neo4J to find the records in my RDBMS database, by executing the search on Neo4J which will return the primary key values that meet the search criteria.

I have written a small C# application using Neo4Client that reads two of the tables from the RDBMS database and creates the nodes and relationships between the nodes.  The two tables in this example are a formula header and its child table, formula ingredients.

On a small database (~50 and ~250 rows in the two tables), my crawl is very quick.  But testing the application with a large customer database (~550K and ~6M rows) the crawls are proving to be too slow.  On some older hardware I use for testing/research I am getting ~4 rows/second (estimating 36 hours to crawl the 550K table).  On my newer development system, I am getting ~14 rows/second (estimating 10 hours to crawl the 550K table).

I know that the Neo4JClient driver uses the Neo4J REST interface, and given this similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10983967/neo4jclient-data-import), it seems like Neo4J will not be suitable for my project.

I've thought about multi-threading, but I don't think that will fit this scenario. I do intend on multi-threading this application but not at the individual table being crawled.  The tables in the RDMBS that I want to crawl are logically related, hence the Neo4J Relationships, and there are several sets of these table groups.  I had planned on spinning a thread per table set. Ultimately, I would have 75 tables in 12 sets of tables that I would need to crawl, and I think this level of performance would be impractical on a production environment.

I have [posted](http://db.tt/5IbvH7iX) my sample code with the hopes that someone can tell me I am doing something in a less than optimal way.  One thing I would like to know if there is a way to create a node with an index *and* a relationship?  Currently that is a two-step process, albeit it will not impact the performance numbers I mention above because the code for the 550K table doesn't use relationships.  My test app first creates the header nodes (the 550K table, which is what the performance figures I mention above are based on), and then creates the ingredient nodes and the relationship to the header node.  I anticipate that when I test the creation of the ingredient nodes, my performance numbers will be even slower.

Thanks!

Comment: How often will you be crawling the rdbms? Is it a 'constant' thing - or a one off?

Comment: It is not a one-off.  As the main application database is updated, so to will this Neo4J database need to be updated.  I saw elsewhere about a data import into Neo4J, but that is not appropriate here.  I intended for the Neo4J database to have a full crawl as needed/requested, with incremental crawls on some set schedule.

Comment: How frequently is the rdbms updated - speed wise, is this going to cause issues? obviously the initial load is slow, but is the update not quick enough either? if the performance is too slow - your best bet would probably be to go with a native java application (i'm afraid!) PS. i'm looking at the code to see if there is anything that can be done...

Comment: It's updated relatively quickly as users add/edit/update records.  This is for a commercial software package (.Net based), so one implementation is going to be different than the next, and I'm attempting to make something that will work in a wide variety of scenarios.  I was hoping to avoid having a native java application, as that is outside of my wheelhouse.